# Crafting multiple items without confirming for each item?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I often find the process of melting massive amounts ore or crafting multiple items tedious, as I can only craft one item at the time, and then pressing the confirmation button.

Is there an easier way to smelt/craft an item multiple times, instead of pressing the craft button, and then confirming it for each single item?

Comment: I usually just use the keyboard shortcut keys, it goes by pretty fast when I spam it

Comment: Similar to @yx, on the PC, I just position my mouse where the 'OK' button is, and then spam **E**->**Mouseclick**, repeat.

Comment: @yx I do that too, but I still find the process tedious, and would much rather have an easier way of doing it.

Comment: Or spam E and Y, for Yes. Does not require use of the mouse.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz you don't even need to alternate E's and mouseclicks. Clicking in the area where "yes" appears will attempt to smith the currently selected item, same as if you had pressed E.

Comment: @Raven Which is due to a UI bug that has other consequences, which Bethsoft is in theory patching next week.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is not a way to craft multiple items as the comment have implied.  Spamming E and Y seems to be the best solution for now.

It seems likely there will be a mod when the creation kit shows up that will improve this situation (for PC).  I'll update this when it becomes available.  (That is my primary reason for the answer, to make this easy to find and update later).

Comment: Stack Exchange has a 'Favorites' feature. Just click on the star below the question votes to favorite, and the question will be saved in your favorites page on your profile.

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered by accident that you don't need to press "E" every time. After the first time, if you just keep clicking right where the "yes" was (what looks like empty space), it will bring up the prompt again (so essentially each double click = an item).

Just watch out! If you finish the item you're crafting, it may move to the next one on the list, and you'll end up crafting things you didn't want.

Comment: This information was posted nearly 4 years ago in this very question, in the form of [this comment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36646/crafting-multiple-items-without-confirming-for-each-item/231637#comment53431_36646)

Comment: Well then it's about time someone put it where it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

I use a logitech keyboard g series. Create a macro with the g keys and then in the game you just hold the key down and relax.